# what is really an iteration in pymc

Tags: python, pymc

I have a model in pymc, simplified

```
import pymc as pm
a = pm.Normal('a', 0,5)
b = pm.Normal('b', 0,5)
cnt = 0

@pm.deterministic
def mu(a=a, b=b):
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    return a + b*x # x and y were loaded from csv
y_hat = pm.Normal('y', mu, 1, observed=True, value=y)

mc = pm.MCMC([a,b,mu,y_hat])
mc.sample(100)
print (cnt)
```

result:

```
240
```

After the model runs, I expect `cnt` to be 100, but printing it gives around 240 (not every sampling returns the same, but it's about that number). I thought `pymc` was maybe doing some tuning in the first few, but running even a few thousand iterations, `cnt` is always about 2 times more than the mcmc iterations.

- What is the reason for that?
- Can I control this using manual tuning?

Answer (score 0):

The number of times `mu` is evaluated is not related to the number of iterations in any MCMC run. I would not expect them to be equivalent. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to fit a dynamic model, in which `mu` is actually a set of difference equations that take a few seconds to run. Therefore running a few thousand iterations takes a day, and if `mu` is evaluated more then the fitted parameter (`y) that makes it sometimes 3 days.

Comment: I would suggest profiling the data to see what is taking it so long. Is it a very large dataset? MCMC does not scale well to large data. If that is the case, you might look at PyMC3, which includes non-sampling approaches to inference, namely variational inference.

Comment: The data is small. The model itself is long. One run of it, outside the scope of `pymc` is the time consumer - it is a dynamic model with about 200 compartments on about 1000 timestamps.

Comment: It might be worth checking whether you can batch update several of your parameters. Parameters within the same `Container` will be batch updated, which speeds things up. Again, using VI in PyMC3 might also help, but if you have already coded a large model, you may not want to port it.